# PHP REGEX Exclude Certain Tags?

Tags: php, html, regex

For REGEX, I am wondering how I would clear all HTML tags entered except for the simple ones, such as `<a>, <b>, <i>, <pre>`. I know that I can use this regex to exclude all html charicters, but I am not sure how I would go about only removing some, and deleting the others while conserving the content inside. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using an HTML parser instead?

Comment: If regex is absolutely necessary, please state so. Otherwise, use a built in PHP function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the second parameter in :

http://php.net/strip_tags

Essentially, you can call this function and list the tags you don't' want to be stripped.

Comment: It's not the requested regex, but regex is a but redundant for this. I agree that `strip_tags` should be used for this, and question should be revised to, "Is there a way to only allow certain HTML tags in PHP?"